# "this" in .each function not pointing to .each's caller

Tags: javascript, class, joomla, mootools

In jQuery,

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){return this;})
```

will retrun every elements with class .myClass. I suppose this is also the case for mootools's  .each function. However, when I try to read the following codes, I got confused(the 'attach' function is the method in question, so you can skip other codes):

```
var Mosaic = new Class({

        Implements: //some codes,

        options: //some codes

        initialize: function(options){
            this.setOptions(options);

            this.mosaics = document.getElements('[data-mosaic]');
            this.mosaic = {};
            this.settings = {};
            try {
                RokMediaQueries.on('every', this.mediaQuery.bind(this));
            }
            catch(error) { if (typeof console != 'undefined') console.error('Error while trying to add a RokMediaQuery "match" event', error); }
        },

        attach: function(mosaic, settings){
            mosaic = typeOf(mosaic) == 'number' ?
                    document.getElements('[data-mosaic=' + this.getID(mosaic) + ']')
                    :
                    mosaic;
            settings = typeOf(settings) == 'string' ? JSON.decode(settings) : settings;

            var containers = (mosaic ? new Elements([mosaic]).flatten() : this.mosaics);

            containers.each(function(container){
                container.store('roksprocket:mosaic:attached', true);
                this.setSettings(container, settings, 'restore');
                // ..... 

        setSettings: //some functions
        // .....
    });
```

In the 'attach' method, there is a call of containers.each, wherein 'this' is not pointing to the current element of 'containers', insteadly, it is pointing to the instances created through Mosaic CLass. Somewhere in the codes, there is something like:

```
myDemonstrate = new Mosaic();
myDemonstrate.attach(somekey, someJson);
```

And I set a breakpoint on the line

```
this.setSettings(container, settings, 'restore');
```

and at this point, "this" is actually the object myDemonstrate.

So, why is the "this" here not the .each functions's caller? Does it have to do with the fact that it is inside the Mosaic() function?

(RokSprocketMosaic is a joomla extension developed by RocketTheme,  if needed, you can find Mosaic.js file here: http://fbnychoir.org/components/com_roksprocket/layouts/mosaic/themes/default/mosaic.js)

Comment: So, `container !== this`? Where is the end of your `.each()` call? Are you passing `this` to `.each()` by any chance? Or are you binding the callback to `this`?

Comment: `containers` sure looks like an array or object returned from mosaic, and as long as it has length, `each` will iterate over it I suppose

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I overlooked the bind argument (which is "this") for the .each function, therefore the "this" inside the .each function refers to the myDemonstrate instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MooTools `.each()` iterator behaves like ES5's `.forEach()` i.e. it will pass the array element and resp index to the function. And the `this` corresponds to the execution context, or can be set by passing the `bind` argument to the method.

As [@DimitarChristoff refered in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728047/this-in-each-function-not-pointing-to-eachs-caller/25729095?noredirect=1#comment40232552_25729095), if the `bind`argument is not supplied, the `this` will depend on your document standards mode - either `global object` or `undefined` in strict mode. under.

#### Excert from [the docs at mootools.net](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array:each):

#### *Array method: each()*

Calls a function for each element in the array.

#### Syntax:

```
myArray.each(fn[, bind]);
```

#### Arguments:

1. fn   - (*function*) The function which should be executed on each item in the array. This function is passed the item and its index in the array.
2. bind - (*object*, optional) The object to be used as 'this' in the function. For more information see [Function:bind][].

Argument: fn

> **Syntax**: fn(item, index, array)

Arguments:

1. item   - (*mixed*) The current item in the array.
2. index  - (*number*) The current item's index in the array.
3. array  - (*array*) The actual array.

#### Examples:

```
//Alerts "0 = apple", "1 = banana", and so on:

['apple', 'banana', 'lemon'].each(function(item, index){
    alert(index + " = " + item);
}); 

//The optional second argument for binding isn't used here.
```

So the `this`, in your code, corresponds to the MooTools Class, so calling `this.setSettings()` will call the Class's method `setSettings` which is the last line of the code you posted.

Comment: strictly speaking - this is not entirely true. in mootools each just as in es5 forEach, there is a 3rd argument for context. if not supplied, it will depend on your document standards mode - either global object or undefined in strict mode. you can pass this as the last argument or use function.prototype.bind on the iterator to change it.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, you are right. Edited to be more correct and naming the optional argument.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I actually overlooked a critical part of the codes. Thanks to your answer, I realize it and now not only this quesiton is solved, but also I have more insight about how "bind" works, which has been perplexing me for a long time too.
The critical missing code I mentioned above is :
`containers.each(function(container){
                // ..... 
 }, this)`
Sorry for the layout. But with the "this" as the bind argument, no wonder the "this" inside the .each call refers to the "myDemonstrate" instance.

Comment: A follow-up question.

I have always been thinking that when we would need to use the automatically passed argument for .each's function argument, since we can just call it using "this". Bear with my English, I mean in the following code:
`$('.class').each(function(o){})`
I thought we didn't need to use 'o' since we can use 'this'.
But now I see the purpose of 'o': if we do 
`$('.class').each(function(o){},otherObject)`
then all the 'this' inside function(o){} would be the 'otherObject', hence we have to use 'o' to refer to the iterating element. 

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @WenShenk exactly, this is were the power of the "object oriented" comes to place in MooTools. The whole Class system is really really nice in MooTools.

Answer (score -1):

.each() function in Jquery is similar to foreach function. if you doesn't initialize parameter to the .each() function, then it returns whole element as an object.

for example, A web page have bundle of div element with Div class, if we refer like

```
$(".Div").each(function(){ return this; })
```

it will return whole element as an object like { div1, div2,.... }

If you need to return this as a single element you have to set an index and element to the parameter of each function like

```
$(".Div").each(function(index, element){ 
return this; // this returns only one element until the object ends. 
});
```